# ExpandableListView; When I click on first group's switchCompat, other group's switchCompat click on and vise versa

Tags: android, click, expandablelistview

I created an ExpandableListView but I have had many errors. Sometimes I get that "Flat list position is of unknown type". Sometimes I don't get this error but when I click on any group's SwitchCompact child, other group's SwitchCompact child also clicked. My adapter is below:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private String company_name_array[] = { "PO" ,  "Opet" ,  "Shell" ,  "BP" };
    private int company_icon_array[] = { R.drawable.po,
            R.drawable.opet, R.drawable.shell,
            R.drawable.bp };

    static public List<String> stationList;
    static public List<String> fuelList;
    static public boolean density;
    private ImageView image1;
    private ImageView image2;
    private TextView text1;
    private TextView text2;
    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        stationList = new ArrayList<>();
        fuelList = new ArrayList<>();
        density = false;
    }

    public ExpandableListAdapter()
    {

    }
    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item2, null);
            /*holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.toogle = (SwitchCompat) convertView.findViewById(R.id.switch2);
            holder.toogle.setText(childText);*/
        }
        /*else
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.toogle = (SwitchCompat) convertView.findViewById(R.id.switch2);
            holder.toogle.setText(childText);
        }
        holder.toogle.setText(childText);*/

        SwitchCompat toogle = (SwitchCompat) convertView.findViewById(R.id.switch2);
        toogle.setText(childText);
        if(groupPosition == 0)
        {
            /*ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.company_icon);
            TypedArray img = this._context.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.company_icon);

            for(int i = 0; i < company_name_array.length; i++)
            {
                if(company_name_array[i].contains(childText) && childText.contains(company_name_array[i]))
                {
                    image.setBackgroundResource(img.getResourceId(i, -1));
                    break;
                }
            }*/
            clickToogle(toogle);
        }
        else if(groupPosition == 1)//il
        {

        }
        else if(groupPosition == 2)//akaryakıt
        {
            clickToogleFuel(toogle);

        }
        else if(groupPosition == 3)//yoğunluk
        {
            clickToogleDensity(toogle);
        }

        //txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public SwitchCompat toogle;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public List<String> getArrayList()
    {
        return stationList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can anybody help me?

Comment: I solved it. I use myMap = new HashMap<String,Boolean>();